# [openlayer]Is there a way to adjust the pitch of map using openlayer's v6?

Tags: api, openlayers, pitch

**I cannot find any params from pitch of map.**
Is there a way to adjust the pitch of map using openlayer's v6

Comment: There is limited support with third party extensions, e.g. https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map/map.perspective.html